# Does the Battle chest have all the data?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Do CDs 1 and 2 from the 4.0 WoW Battle chest have the full data?
I'm getting World of Warcraft Battle chest soon, so I just want to know.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the data"?

Comment: You don't have to download all data(20GB+) to be able to play :)
I am almost sure you will be able to play straight forward after game installation from dvds.

Answer (score 7):

**No, they do not**.  Since the disks were printed, there have been patches that will need to be downloaded and installed.  This is true of any MMO; a disk cannot be completely up to date, and you will always need to download more updates in order to play the game.